# Why doesn't 0.1+0.2-0.3 equal 0.0?

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, addition

Why doesn't 0.1+0.2-0.3 equal 0.0 ? according to normal equation the result should be 0 but why isn't it?

Could someone please explain me the reason?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score -1):

All programming languages including Python use **32-bit floating point** representation for numbers. **With decimal fractions, this floating-point number system causes some rounding errors** which results in `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` as `false`.

[The Actual Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGlIG.jpg)

For Example:

`1.2` is exactly equal to `1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`

Solution:

One solution to handle this inconsistency in floating-point value is by using a native Python module called **[Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)**

---

For Detailed Answer, Read these articles:

https://gauravkk22.medium.com/why-0-1-0-2-0-3-is-false-in-js-mystery-unsolved-with-solution-4f7db2755f18

https://python.plainenglish.io/floating-point-arithmetic-precision-error-in-python-decimal-comes-for-rescue-8803d1290601https://python.plainenglish.io/floating-point-arithmetic-precision-error-in-python-decimal-comes-for-rescue-8803d1290601

Comment: floating point yes, 32 bits ... rarely. Almost everyone uses 64-bit floats.

Comment: python uses 64 bit floats; 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 is the 64 bit value

Comment: add it in binary, considering rounding--that will explain it